# Get multiple results for different ids from single python requests

Tags: python-requests

I want to get info for different user_ids from an API using python requests, I can use a loop and change the id every time, but it is slow, is there a simple way to do this?

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

url = "....../api"
paras = {
    'username': 'guest',
    'password': '123456',
    'method': 'location_info',
    'barcode': ['1150764','1150765'],
}
r = requests.get(url, params=paras, verify = False)
pprint(r.json())
```

The result only return the info for latter barcode '1150765'. Is there a way to query 100 barcodes at the same time?

Comment: Sounds like you want asynchronous IO - look into `asyncio` and in particular `aiohttp`.

Comment: There's probably no way of doing what you're asking unless the API itself allows it. You could use aiohttp as the user above said or use the threading module for an easier to make but less effective way. But first, I'd consult the API docs in order to be sure multiple barcodes can/cannot be submitted.

Comment: Thanks, the use of `requests.Session()` reduces some of the time. I'll look into asynchronous IO as well as asking the API provider.